# MessageBox - Force it to be blocking

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, sapui5, messagebox, blocking

In order to keep a clean, easy and maintainable code, I want to exit a function, after the user has closed a MessageBox.... BUT the anonymous function is triggered async, therefore not blocking.
Is there a best practice to achieve this? I always was in love with c#'s MessageBox implementation.... so I expected this in UI5, too. So sad. Here the code...

```
                    } else { } */
                
                MsgBox.error(info,                  
                    {
                    actions: [MsgBox.Action.OK], emphasizedAction: MsgBox.Action.NO,
                                onClose: function (sAction) 
                                {
                                    abort = true;                 
                                }
                });
            }

            if(abort){

                return;
            }

            this.clearLocalModel();
            // code
            // more code
            // which is executed , but should not
            // I KNOW, i can redesign this with if else... and so on- BUT
            // i would like to keep it pretty simple...
```

UPDATE:

I tried the idea with the promise, returning a bool.
As "promised" I returned for feedback, and I am in the same situation like before... in this case I added screenshots, I hope, You don't mind...

Caller:

[image]

Callee:

[image]

Comment: Use a Promise, await it and resolve it in your callback.

Comment: This is not possible. JS can block the thread where it's executed, but rendering and event firing are run in the same thread, that means your JS can't detect clicks on the pop-up or anything else, the browser is paralyzed while the script is running. Just write your asynchronous code in "_clean, easy and maintainable_" manner.

Comment: Could you share a sample use case for the abort based on the `MessageBox.error()`? What would you like to abort? If the user has unsaved chages? Trying to understand what the actual goal is..

Comment: you have to do with asynchronous.
Instead of wanting to make your asynchronous "synchronous", which is certainly not a good practice, and doing an IF abort === true ELSE well put your IF code in the success callback and the else code in the error callback..
To make it more readable, name the callback functions (example onCloseMessageBoxXXX)

Comment: @BoghyonHoffmann: The user must not create another order, if there is already one for the chosen material. And, later on, if a special check returns true, the user will be able to create it anyway, with a different MessageBox, allowing yes/no.

Comment: Instead of procedural, a "clean, easy and maintainable code" would be to create one function for each situation: one for handling the successful user creation, and another one for handling the failing case. It seems the function you attempt to exit is doing multiple things rather than one thing.

Comment: @BoghyonHoffmann: No, it is not. It checks, whether an order can be created, if so, it does, else it shall EXIT. That's where I usually in other languages do an RETURN after an user info.

Answer (score 1):

On a very high level you could create something like the following function. It presents a `MessageBox` and depending on what the user clicks resolves or rejects a promise.

```js
askUserForToContinue: function() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        MessageBox.error(info, {
            actions: [MsgBox.Action.OK],
            onClose: (sAction) => {
                if (sAction === MsgBox.Action.OK) {
                    // return true, flow should continue
                    resolve(true);
                } else {
                    // return false, flow should continue
                    resolve(false);
                }
            }
        });
     
    }
}
```

Then from somewhere else you can call this function and wait for the result (using `then` or `async/await` which both will feel more like a synchronous flow).

```js
handleFlow: async function() {
    if (await this.askUserForToContinue()) {
        // Promise was resolved with true, do stuff (ideally call another method)
    } else {
        // Promise was resolved with false, do other stuff (ideally call another method)
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it would be more usable if the function just returned true or false instead of throwing an exception with value `undefined` (which is never a good idea anyway)... Then you'd write `if (await this.askUserForInput()) { ... }`

Comment: @Marc: Wow, this is really kind... directly with example... and as it seems, this is a pattern-worthy  sample... I will try this ( and the idea to return a bool or catch it will be taken into consideration as well )... will be back for feedback.

Comment: Updated my initial post with my try error results... basically my aim is, to exit the current function, after the user has checked "ok" from the message box... I think, we just aded an async overhead with no benefit in this case...
...any clues? 

Else I would continue with refactoring of the process-flow as I initially wanted to avoid...

Comment: Well if you are waiting for a user action and you don't know how long you have to wait then imo this is exactly what **async** means. Are there any other options for the user except to press "OK"?

Comment: @icbytes I have checked your update. You didn't use my proposed `asnyc/await` but `then`. This means that your call to `this.clearXXXX()` has to happen inside the `then` so it's part of the async flow. E.g. `if (result) { this.clearXXXX }`. Also I don't see the rest of your `promtForXXXX` method but make sure to return a Promise in the `else` also.